# Extract points from given Line[]

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

As the title says, I have a `Line` object like this:

```
Line[{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},...,{7,8,9}}]
```

and want to extract certain points. I have no clue how to do this.
Thanks for help

Comment: `Line[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}][[1, 1]]` yields `{1, 2, 3}`.

Answer (score 4):

Using the third argument of `Extract`:

```
ClearAll[extractPoints]
extractPoints = Extract[#, {1, ## & @@ #} & /@ #2, Point] &;
```

Example:

```
line = Line[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}];
extractPoints[line, {3, {1, 2}, {2, 3}}]
```

> {Point[{7, 8, 9}], Point[2], Point[6]}